# Building a Shunt Active Power Filiter Using

Tags: schematics, active-filter, injection-current

I am trying to built an experimental setup of a shunt active power filter to validate some Matlab simulations, I am using a SEMITEACH B6U+E1CIF+B6CI. ([Here is the datasheet)](http://shop.semikron.com/out/media/ds/SEMIKRON_DataSheet_SEMITEACH_IGBT_3M50GB123D_1M50GAL123D_P3_250F_08753450.pdf) and picture of the device :

[image]

The SEMITEACH module contains an 3 phase uncontrollable rectifier that i am using to power DC motor to form a nonlinear load.

The SEMITEACH also contains an IGBT 3 phase inverter connected internally to an internal capacitor, I want to use that VSI as and this capacitor into the shunt active power filter that will compensate for harmonics caused by the non linear load. Here is the schematic I followed :

[image: Schema]

So far, I was able to generate the compensation current, **my problem is the injection of this current into the PCC**, honestly I never tried injecting power into the grid, and I am afraid of damaging an equipment because I don't know if I am doing it right, so here is my question :

Once the compensation currents generated using the VSI, am I supposed to just shunt the output of the VSI directly to the PCC? Or should i use a device or something to inject this power?

Comment: Are you basically asking what the circuit diagram is of the item in the picture because the rest of what you are saying doesn't make any sense to me and the circuit (more a block diagram) doesn't really explain anything that you are trying to do and there are no references to terms that you mention such as "VSI", "PCC" and a "compensation circuit". Are you expecting folk to become quite familiar with the data sheet you linked because, if you are, you may be out of luck because any decent question should be self contained.

Comment: When you want to inject power from a inverter into the point of common coupling ? do you just connect the wires or use an interface to transfer power ? i don't know how to say more clearly ?????

Comment: Then why are you saying all sorts of things in your question that appear to be irrelevant? If all you want to know is how a local power source can connect up to a power grid with safety why don't you say that and forget all the stuff that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: How will you inject all the harmonics of a pulse and dominant 3rd & 5th with a series LRC active resonator? by tuning out the fundamental and have enough voltage gain to reduce current error ??  good luck with phase margin and overshoot injecting more noise. Possible yes but not with CT mismatch errors., note that without V sensing there is no PFC and if the transformer is going into excitation saturation it will generate harmonics

Comment: @Andyaka Because i thought the answer may vary depending on the scenario ! this is why i added all those details, i didn't know that it is all cases of connecting a local power source can connect up to a power grid are the same, could you please answer this question and give me clarifications ! please !

Comment: Before anyone answers a question, the question (not the comments amending the question) has to be clear else the answerer risks downvotes from people not being able to relate the answer to the baffling question.